# PHP looping through multilevel Alphavantage API JSON

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am using an API from Alphavantange.co to get share price values. I need to loop through all of the values that are provided by the API.

I have returned the JSON from the api and use json_decode.
I can get 1 value e.g I can get 63.3700 to echo to the screen using the code below:

```
<?php
  $string = file_get_contents("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=LLOY.l&outputsize=full&apikey=XXXX");
        $arr = json_decode($string, true);


                            echo $arr['Time Series (Daily)']['2019-04-04']['1. open'].'<br>';
?>
```

The api returns the following (example of the first few records)

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
        "2. Symbol": "LLOY.l",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-04-05",
         "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2019-04-05": {
            "1. open": "62.4500",
            "2. high": "62.9000",
            "3. low": "62.0800",
            "4. close": "62.2100",
            "5. adjusted close": "62.2100",
            "6. volume": "218007230",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-04-04": {
        "1. open": "63.3700",
        "2. high": "63.3800",
        "3. low": "62.3500",
        "4. close": "62.6200",
        "5. adjusted close": "62.6200",
        "6. volume": "193406609",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
    },
    "2019-04-03": {
        "1. open": "64.1200",
        "2. high": "65.5400",
        "3. low": "63.9300",
        "4. close": "64.8800",
        "5. adjusted close": "62.7400",
        "6. volume": "231702090",
        "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
        "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
```

I can get one value at a time but ultimately need to loop through all of the values to write them to a MySQL table. How to I loop through them when each level has a different 'name' (different date)?

As a first help, how would I output the Open value for each date, e.g.
2019-04-05 62.4500
2019-04-04 63.3700
2019-04-03 64.1200

Comment: I want to be able to output each 'open' value that is returned in the JSON with the date. Added more information to the question. Thanks

Comment: And what about `foreach( $arr['Time Series (Daily)'] AS $date => $results) { foreach( $results AS $key => $value ) { echo '<br>For ' . $key . ' on ' . $date . ' the value is ' . $value; } }`

Comment: @cale_b That is a great help. Give me enough to start to understand how to solve the problems I'm having to reach my goal and hopefully continue with the project.. Do you want to add it as an answer and I will +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the array to get access to all of it's elements.  Due to the structure of the data, you'll likely want a nested loop like so:

```
$arr = json_decode( $string, TRUE );

// check if the array key exists
if ( ! empty( $arr['Time Series (Daily)'] ) {
    // loop over the contents of Time Series
    foreach( $arr['Time Series (Daily)'] AS $date => $results ) { 
        // loop over the results for each date in Time Series
        foreach( $results AS $key => $value ) { 
            echo '<br>For ' . $key . ' on ' . $date . ' the value is ' . $value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the JSON to an array, you can use function `json_decode` to convert JSON to the array and apply logic inside a loop

```
$responseToArray = json_decode($response, TRUE);//$response is JSON
```

Now you can use the loop

```
foreach($responseToArray as $key => $value){
     /* 
      Your Code here, you can further do the
      loop through $value ...and so on
      */
}
```

Refer to [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more details.